# Jboss AS 5 web sessions in infinispan

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x, infinispan

How can I get JBoss AS 5 web sessions to be maintained in Infinispan?

Comment: You want to _store_ the sessions in infinispan?

Comment: Yes. Thats exactly what I want.

Comment: I don't think there's a simple configuration you can change to achieve this. Have a read over [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856324/tomcat-store-session-in-database/4856407#4856407). I know the question doesn't ask about Infinistore, but the idea is exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the source code of JBoss AS 6 and JBoss AS 7, both of which use Infinispan for HTTP sessions.  May not be that simple to implement though.  Personally, I think your best bet would be to upgrade to JBoss AS 6 or 7.